# Laravel 5.7 : 404 or 403 on storage/app/private whereas it works on storage/app/public

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.7

I am struggling to offer the user a link to a file that they can download when logged in. I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44247272/laravel-5-4-forbidden-403-on-files-in-storage-with-public-visibility) and [that (because eventually I want to protect the file from public access)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30682421/how-to-protect-image-from-public-view-in-laravel-5).

So under my app /storage folder I created a "private" directory next to "public". Inside it there is a subfolder "A" containing a "fileA.tar.gz" (I also tried with a simple test.txt without luck).

```
MyLaravelApp/
├── storage/
│   ├── public/
│   ├── private/
│        └── A/
│            └──fileA.tar.gz
```

In my controller I do :

```
$softwarePath = "private/A/fileA.tar.gz";

$urlToArchive = \Storage::disk('local')->url(
                                $softwarePath);

$exists = \Storage::disk('local')->exists($softwarePath); // returns true
```

But in the view when I click on the link `http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/private/A/fileA.tar.gz` I get 404 although the `exists` function returns `true`.

So I tried to define in /config/filesystems.php a direct "short-cut" to my "private" folder :

```
'private' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root' => storage_path('app/private'),
    'url' => env('APP_URL').'/privateDownload',
    'visibility' => 'public',
],
```

and made the following changes in the controller :

```
$softwarePath = "A/fileA.tar.gz";

$urlToArchive = \Storage::disk('private')->url($softwarePath);

$exists = \Storage::disk('private')->exists($softwarePath); // keeps returning true
```

But now I get 403 when I click on the generated link `http://localhost/privateDownload/A/fileA.tar.gz` (note the localhost without port address) and if I change the address to localhost:8000 I get the 404 back.

The route to the aforementioned controller is :

```
Route::get('/account', 'AccountController@showAccountDetails')->middleware('auth');
```

And I also tried to remove the `middleware('auth')` and access to `private/A/fileA.tar.gz` without luck (404).

Please note : if I keep the same subdirectory hierachy and moved it under public like :

```
MyLaravelApp/
├── storage/
│   ├── public/
│        └── A/
│            └──fileA.tar.gz 
│   ├── private/
```

There is no issue, and the file can be downloaded. This is not interesting because I want to prevent this file from being downloaded without being logged in.

According to the [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/filesystem#file-urls) and other SO answers it seems possible to access to a different directory than `public`. How can it be done ? Why `exists()` returns true whereas I get 404 then ? What's my setup / code failure actually?

Any help appreciated!

**Solution**

Based on @Namoshek's answer, here is what I did (for the records) :

In the aforementioned controller I simply checked whether or not the user has the right to download fileA. If so then I return a view which has a link to a route named `downloadFileA` that points to a function `downloadFileA` still in the same aforementioned controller.

Finally in the function `downloadFileA` I return `\Storage::disk('private')->download('fileA')` after checking whether the user is entitled or not to download the file. So I check twice but that's not a problem because there is very low traffic (once a week or so).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Storage::download('filename.xyz')` instead of generating a URL with `Storage::url('filename.xyu')`. This will send the file as content of the response. It may be resource intensive for large files though.

Comment: Thanks @Namoshek! I updated my question with the solution I used based on your answer.

Comment: Note about your comment in the solution `So I check twice but that's not a problem because there is very low traffic (once a week or so)`: It is actually required for you to check the permissions twice (at least from what I got from the requirements). Otherwise a user with the permission to see or download the file could simply send the link to someone else. And to be fair, such a permission check does not cost a lot of resources at all.